# How do I use use dialogs in an electron + react environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

([clone the repo & try it](https://github.com/arcandio/fstest2))

I'm working on a desktop app using node, create-react-app, and electron. The following line, [recommended here](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog)

```
const { dialog } = require('electron').remote
```

when added to my `store` react component (and thus not in the electron main process), causes the following error:

```
TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
getElectronPath
F:/freelance/repos/creative-ontology-editor/node_modules/electron/index.js:8
   5 | var pathFile = path.join(__dirname, 'path.txt');
   6 | 
   7 | function getElectronPath() {
>  8 |   if (fs.existsSync(pathFile)) {
   9 |     var executablePath = fs.readFileSync(pathFile, 'utf-8');
  10 | 
  11 |     if (process.env.ELECTRON_OVERRIDE_DIST_PATH) {
```

I believe this is because React or create-react-app specifically blocks/nullifies certain node.js modules like `fs`, but I could be wrong. Note that this error happens *inside* the `electron` module when I include the above line, not in my own code.

My goal is to have my desktop app able to save and load files to the user's machine, the way something like Word or Excel does.

I've called `const fs = window.require('fs');` in my react component, which I think I'm not supposed to do, but also, since this is in the actual `electron` module's `index.js`, I made sure that it also calls it, which it does: `var fs = require('fs')`. There was no change in behavior when I switched my call in the react component to `const fs = window.require('fs')`.

I've also made sure to set `webPreferences.nodeIntegration` to true in my electron main process, to no avail.

Comment: Let's exclude the simplest cause first: did you call `const fs = require('fs');`?

Comment: @ChrisG I updated the question with those details.

Comment: Check if you have ` webPreferences: {   nodeIntegration: false  }` somewhere

Comment: @LeonardoBuscemi Not that I can find. As I understand it, `create-node-app` manages a lot of configuration and requirements without me being able to see them. Could it be hidden behind that veil?